# Return status 500 if sendgrid authentication fails in angular express node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, sendgrid

I'm trying to get a status 500 to the client when they submit a form and sendgrid authentication fails.

Right now I have no idea what I'm doing wrong because I have some code that returns status 500 with the same code.

Everytime I submit the form and have (on purpose) a wrong password for sendgrid, the node console logs the error, but my client side gets a status of 200 as a success.

I want to correct this.

Here's my code:

```
// sendgrid configuration with secret key
var options = {
  auth: {
    api_key: process.env.SENDGRID_KEY
  }
}

var client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

app.post('/contact_us_form',function(req,res){
  //Your NodeMailer logic comes here

  var data = req.body;

  //Validates user input for contact form
  function validate (){
    //Validates email with regeex
    var  validateEmail = function (email) {
      var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
      return re.test(email);
    }
    if(data.contactName.length < 50 && validateEmail(data.contactEmail) && data.contactMsg.length < 250)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  var email = {
    from: data.contactEmail,
    to: 'example@email.com',
    subject: 'Message from ' + data.contactName,
    text: data.contactMsg
  };


  if(validate()){
    client.sendMail(email, function (err, info){
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        console.log(email);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Message sent ' + info);
        console.log(email);
        res.json(data);
      }
    });
  }else{
    res.status(500).send('Data invalid: ' + validate);
  }

  res.json(data);
});
```

Notice this part:

```
if(validate()){
  client.sendMail(email, function (err, info){
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      console.log(email);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Message sent ' + info);
      console.log(email);
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
}else{
  res.status(500).send('Data invalid: ' + validate);
}
```

I get the status 500 if the `validate` function fails and the status 500 is sent to client side as normal.

When the authentication fails for sendgrid, I get the:

```
if (err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + err);
  console.log(email);
  res.status(500).send(err);
}
```

but the `res.status(500).send(err)` seems to not be doing anything here, on the client side I still get status 200

This is what I get in the node console logs though:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2015:20:48:26 +0000] "POST /contact_us_form HTTP/1.1" 200 147 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
Error: Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked
{ from: 'example@emailfrom.com',
  to: [ 'example@emailto.com' ],
  subject: 'Message from Johhan',
  text: 'asdfasdfsafsdasdfasdfsafsdasdfasdfsafsdasdfasdfsafsdasdfasdfsafsd',
  headers: {},
  toname: [ '' ],
  cc: [],
  bcc: [],
  files: undefined }
```

Here's the code for handling the front-end:

```
function sendMail () {

  var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/contact_us_form',
   headers: {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
   },
   data: 
    { 
      contactName : self.contactName,
      contactEmail : self.contactEmail,
      contactMsg : self.contactMsg
    }
  };

  $http(req).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config){
      console.log('message sent:');
      console.log('data: ' + data);
      console.log('status: ' + status);
      console.log('headers: ' + headers);
      console.log('config: ' + config);

      // displays success message
      $('.position-fixed-alerts.alert-success').slideDown().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

      // resets form inputs fields
      $('.form input, .form textarea').val('');

      // disables form after clicking
      $scope.isDisabled = true;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config){
      console.log('data: ' + data);
      console.log('status: ' + status);
      console.log('headers: ' + headers);
      console.log('config: ' + config);

      $('.position-fixed-alerts.alert-danger').slideDown().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });

};
```

In here, I keep getting the success one even tho the node console brings an error.

This is the screenshot of what it logs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Added these for easier debug:

```
console.log("--== DEBUG ==--"); // ADDED
if(validate()){
  console.log(`validate(): ${validate()}`); // ADDED
  client.sendMail(email, function (err, info){
    console.log("client.sendMail()"); // ADDED
    console.log(`err: ${err}`); // ADDED
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      console.log(email);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Message sent ' + info);
      console.log(email);
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
}else{
  console.log("validate() == false"); // ADDED
  res.status(500).send('Data invalid: ' + validate);
}
console.log("--== DEBUG ==--"); // ADDED
```

Ran the test and got this as logs:

```
--== DEBUG ==--
validate(): true
--== DEBUG ==--
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2015:14:00:37 +0000] "POST /contact_us_form HTTP/1.1" 200 134 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
client.sendMail()
err: Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked
Error: Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked
```

the last `--== DEBUG ==--` is printing out before the other stuff when it's suppose to print last.

Comment: `TypeError: res.statusCode is not a function`

Comment: Oh, whoops lol you're right. What about `res.status(500).end(err)`? (end instead of send). Or better yet, you can even use `res.status(500).json(err)` and keep err as a javascript object; Express will automatically stringify it for you.

Comment: @remus none are working, when I use `res.status(500).end(err)` I get this error: `TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer`, when I use the `.json(err)` it doesn't change anything that I can notice. This is frustrating -_-

Comment: @remus I edited the question with more debugging stuff.

Comment: Are you already setting the status code further back in your code maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it has to do something with javascript not reading the code in order. Maybe create a promise (which I've never done one before), I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: For giggles and sh*ts, can you try a barebones API response in a completely separate node script with that version of express to see if it works?